# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: laravel, database, datatable

I am facing this error on my website while viewing the product page.
its a e-commerce website

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table ‘quietqre_QuietQrewHerbal.product_queries’ doesn’t exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `product_queries` where `product_id` = 15 and `customer_id` != 9)
```

Comment: please add a specific, answerable question to your post

Comment: have you read the error message?

Comment: it says table `quietqre_QuietQrewHerbal.product_queries` does not exist. Given that there's a dot in the name I think you're using a wrong table name somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Table `product_queries` in your database `quietqre_QuietQrewHerbal` is not exist. you need migrate database.

If it's new, use `php artisan migrate`

and if it's old migration and deleted by mistake or etc... find related migration row in `migrations` table (showed in image) and delete just that row, and use `php artisan migrate`

[image]